# How to set my Image Mask in Hexagon Shape in unity?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, image-masking

**I Have hexagon sprites over Image and in back my screenshot image but Here, problem is my image shape square but i want try to fix in hexagon shape**

> So what i do ? please give me any suggestions

frame without image:

[image]

frame with image:

[image: frame image]

Comment: try it out https://youtu.be/g3gpXmo8zRo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create UI Panel And ADD COMPONENT

- Image
- Mask

In Image Component You set Your Any Shape's Image

And Also Add One Image Into Panel That you mask in this Shape

[image]

Check it out for more information https://youtu.be/g3gpXmo8zRo

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the following blog post:
https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/game_development/9781785885822/1/ch01lvl1sec13/adding-a-circular-mask-to-an-image

Basically, you create your hexagon shape in, for example, Gimp, fill it with white color and leave the rest transparent. Be sure to add the alpha channel to your layer. Export as a PNG and apply it to your sprite with the correct unlit transparent shader.